# for-each loop for form validation

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, foreach

Ok, so I have some validation to do on a form with many rows (20+) and 4 fields per row.

- Each column has specific validation requirements
- Rows should be complete, not half filled. Empty rows should be skipped

How do I iterate through the form if each field in the html form has a unique name. For example productCode_1, productCode_2, productCode_3 etc..

```
 <tr>
<td><div align="center">
  <input name="productCode_1" type="text" id="productCode_1" size="7" maxlength="7" />
</div></td>
<td><div align="center">
  <input name="size_1" type="text" id="size_1" size="2" maxlength="2" />
</div></td>
<td><div align="center">
    <input name="quantity_1" type="text" id="quantity_1" size="3" maxlength="3" />
</div></td>
<td><div align="center">
    <input name="price_1" type="text" id="price_1" size="3" maxlength="3" />
</div></td>
```

Above is a sample of the HTML, please note that I don't have permission to modify the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming if you have 20 rows of the HTML you showed then the name=".." names will be like `productCode_1`, `productCode_2` etc.

```
$fields = array('productCode_', 'size_', 'quantity_', 'price_');
$msg = array();  // for error messages
$max_rows = ?; // how many rows to check, cannot see enough of your code to work this one out for you


$ok = true;
for ( $i=1; $i < $max_rows; $i++ ) {

    foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
        if ( ! isset( $field . $i ) )
            $ok = false;
            $msgs[] = "Missing data in $field on row $i";
            // continue is optional, if set will stop processing a row
            // when first error is found, 
            // without it you can report all errors on each row
            continue;   
    }

}

if ( $ok ) {
    // complete form processing
} else {

    // report back all errors
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd put the field names of the fields you like validating in the array, then it'll loop through them. I've put a simple `empty` check, but you'd add you own complex check.

```
    // All the names of the fields you wish to validate.
    $myFieldNames = [];
    $hasErrorOccurred = false;

    foreach ($myFieldNames as $name) {
        if (empty($_POST[$name])) {
            $hasErrorOccurred = true;

            break;
        }
    }

    if ($hasErrorOccurred) {
        // Your error code here.
    } else {
        // Your successful code here.
    }
```

**Reading material:**

[`break;`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)